# POST to JSON using VBA

Tags: json, vba

I created a function to post to an application using VBA tied to an Excel workbook to create many records at once.  So far I can't get a successful post of an authentication method before moving forward with record creation.  Here's what I have so far.

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Row As Integer
Dim sURL As String
Dim sContent As String
Dim oHttp As Object
Dim rContent

Set Sheet = Sheets("APISend")
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
sURL = "https://cityworks.cityofdenton.com:9000/Cityworks/services/AMS/Authentication/Authenticate/"

sContent = Sheet.Range("C1").Value
oHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False
oHttp.send (sContent)
rContent = oHttp.ResponseText
Sheet.Range("D1").Value = rContent
Sheet.Range("E1").Value = sContent
Set Object = Nothing
```

The value in C1 is: {LoginName:"*****",Password:"*****"}

I receive the response: {"Value":false,"Status":1,"Message":"LoginName not populated."}

The following URL string works when pasted into a browser: https://cityworks.cityofdenton.com:9000/Cityworks/services/AMS/Authentication/Authenticate/?data={"LoginName":"*****","Password":"*****"}

I'm new to JSON, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  I've been all over message boards trying what I see, but no luck so far.  Can someone provide the solution?

Thank you!
Tyler

EDIT:
Here's the solution.  For my API, I had to include everything in the sURL variable without using sContent as the Body input.  Code copied below.

```
Set Sheet = Sheets("APISend")
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
sContent = Sheet.Range("C1").Value
sURL = "https://cityworks.cityofdenton.com:9000/Cityworks/services/AMS/Authentication/Authenticate/?data=" & sContent

sContent = Sheet.Range("C1").Value
oHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False
oHttp.send sURL
rContent = oHttp.ResponseText
Sheet.Range("D1").Value = rContent
Sheet.Range("E1").Value = sContent
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your username & password to the `sURL` as parameters? (Without doing this manually, I can't say how this should be specified but probably as `?` parameters on the end of the URL string e.g., `?LoginName=****&Password=****`).

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are not sending a valid `JSON` string:

Make sure the string inside `Range("C1")` has LoginName and Password between quotes like this:

```
{"LoginName":"*****", "Password":"*****"}
```

**EDIT**

After inspecting that `URL` I can say that you need to pass your data inside a querystring `/?data={"LoginName":"*****","Password":"*****"}` for the backend to authenticate. 
Either a `POST` or `GET` reproduce the same results.

However, if you pass your credentials as the request `body`, you will get a `"LoginName not populated."` error.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my string looks like.  I removed the quotes around LoginName and Password at one point to troubleshoot the error, but I get the same response with or without them.

Comment: Well, if that is the case, what do you mean when you say that pasting that url to a browser worked? Are you making a `POST` via VBA when you should be making a `GET` request?